# Huge Delay in fetching the contacts from O365 account through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using the node package `"@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client"` to access Graph API from node environment.

Actually the purpose is to fetch the user contacts `(outlook,live,office, hotmail)` into our system through API,

API `"/me/contacts"` by default fetches only 10 contacts per call, so in our system we are iterating the API using `"skip & @odata.nextLink"` until all the contacts are received.

While referencing the API document it says API request will default provide 10 contacts, so fetching 4k contacts from my account it takes 5+ minutes.

So here there are 3 questions from our side,

1. Is there any query options to fetch maximum contacts in API?
2. To reduce the delay in fetching huge contact list say 8k contacts, is there any other API available to reduce the time delay?
3. We are trying to fetch contact list from multiple O365 account with the volume of more than 3000 contacts in each account, but we are facing lot of delay in getting those contact list through Graph API. Is there any way to get the results or data sets faster from O365 account ?

Comment: Why would you want to get all contacts? You can send a filter with the request.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be using $Top with $Skip to control the page size https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md#98-pagination by default the page size is 10 but with Mailboxes but you should be able to go up 1000 where the Throttling limits will stop anymore being returned in one call.
2. Graph data connect maybe an option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/data-connect-concept-overview